# Why does my Expo app run in Expo Go but not as a development build?

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler, eas

I've created a development build of an Expo app using EAS. Previously I would open the app in Expo Go by running `npx expo start` and scanning the Metro Bundler QR code.

Now, when I try to do the same thing, Expo Go asks whether I want to open the project in Expo Go or as a "Development Build". It works fine in Expo Go, but crashes immediately when I attempt to open the dev build. The error reads:

> null is not an object (evaluating '_ReanimatedModule.default.createNode')

This error is suspiciously similar to one that I encountered earlier in development, which I resolved by downgrading to React Native version 0.69.6. I'm also encountering a second error that says "'main' has not been registered", but I suspect this is downstream of the first error.

I have the same issue when I try to run the app with `npx expo start --dev-client`.

Any ideas why I might be having this problem?

Comment: Same problem here. No solutions so far.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you may have run `expo prebuild` (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/) which removes `"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",` from `app.json`. Try to create a new expo app and look at it's `app.json` file.

When you run `expo prebuild` it changes a few things with your project (see "side effects" in the prebuild docs).

I'm actually working through some issues with that right now too. I thought I had to run prebuild but turns out I didn't have to. Ever since I ran it my app will not load via the dev-client way. I can however switch back to `npx expo start` (NOT `npx expo start --dev-client`, see the `scripts` section of `app.json` as that is also changed when prebuild is run).

Let me know if you are able to get your app to load after re-adding the `main` stuff to `app.json`.

Ps, are you by chance using `react-native-google-mobile-ads`?

Comment: That worked for me, except that I put the `main` inside `package.json`, not `app.json`!

Comment: How would this work with `expo-router/entry` file based routing system?

Comment: I'm using react-native-google-mobile-ads, facing the same issue, any tips?

Comment: @PauloLima Make sure you have a valid `ios_app_id` and `android_app_id` in app.json. 
`"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-********~********",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-********~********"
  }`

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on the same question as @conor909, set the following in your package.json: `"main": "expo-router/entry"`. That worked for me.